# Which SE community is best suited for finding out the purpose of constructed objects?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For example, this question might be offtopic. But where it is not?

[What is the purpose of this construction?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16049/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-construction)