# Q&A Identification of seldom man-made physical objects not being piece of art?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is SE Q&A format relevant for "identification of seldom physical objects observed in real world"?

Questions like "I do not know function of this object (picture) - which purpose does it have?"

In many cases I suppose these question could have civil engineering or handcraft i.e. cultural/historical background. In second case "SE history" might be okay. For first case, I do not know.

[Which SE community is best suited for finding out the purpose of constructed objects?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297684/which-se-community-is-best-suited-for-finding-out-the-purpose-of-construncted-ob?noredirect=1#comment965951_297684)

[image]

Comment: @rene please be so kind to point me which chatrooms do you mean; I suppose that literature and movies chats would designate this question as offtopic as well.

Comment: Looks like _art_ to me, dunno. Art is mostly out of asking for _purpose_ besides on the meta (meta) level.

Comment: It depends per chatroom but maybe the regulars of the engineering chat are willing to give directions. One other option is maybe the chat of HomeImprovement.se but check if any of those rooms have explicit rules that forbid certain questions

Comment: an interesting aspect and opinion that that is art!

Comment: We had our teachers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Beuys

Comment: It really depends on what you're asking about. For example https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296465/230261

Comment: In that one original question, I have seen an object which has been engineered of metal and has unclear purpose to me; actually, neither of SE sites applies.

Comment: "Identify this..." questions have a chequered history on the SE network - to put it mildly.  Identification of random bits of metalwork is unlikely to succeed any better.

Comment: @rene I think it's unfair to use two sites that have major issues with ID and not mention any of the sites that have no problem with them. I've found that, generally, if it's possible to include an image of what you're trying to identify along with a detailed explanation, many sites are happy to accept that sort of question. For example, plant identification and bug/pest identification are both quite common on [gardening.se], tool identification is accepted on [cooking.se] and [crafts.se] and even [gaming.se] accepts ID questions about games if they include an image.

Comment: There is a huge gulf between a half-remembered movie or book plot and identifying something with an image.

Comment: @rene Literature.SE is *not* "struggling" with identification questions. We have a fair few ID questions, nearly all of which have been well-received; there's no problem there. (Movies is a very different story, though.)

Answer (score 3):

SE doesn't claim to solve all of the riddles met in life, the universe and everything (especially not why the answer should be 42).

There doesn't seem to be an appropriate site to tell you what the purpose of that object actually is.

There's no *fine arts* Q&A site settled up at the SE network, which probably could be used to ask about that object. But discussing what belongs in the *fine arts* field or just to the dumpyard, might be not suitable for the SE preferred (non opinion based) Q&A format at all.

Also there might be some historical or cultural background, wich is currently missing for the picture.

There seem to be some plates applicated. What's the text upon these? Might help for identification of the purpose.

Comment: good point; I will revisit the place and tell you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you ran across this thing in your backyard, this sounds like an [identify this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) question on Travel.